# Should the questions about the API be posted only on Stackapps (and not MSE)?

Tags: discussion, tags, api, stackapps

I saw [recent questions about the Stack Exchange API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api?sort=newest) on this website.

Questions about the API have been [posted on StackApps for a long time](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/api+or+apiv2).

So the questions about the API are posted on two different websites.

Should we ban the [api](/questions/tagged/api) tag on MSE and reserve it to StackApps?

Should we flag all the questions which use the [api] tag on Meta Stack Exchange in order to move them to StackApps? Or don't change anything and keep questions on the two websites?

Comment: I would like to see this happen from an organizational standpoint, but StackApps is *dead* compared to MSE.  It's an extremely niche community and gets most of its traffic from SE-API developers and those who *happen* to know about it and *want* a separate view/client.

Comment: @Sean Allred : I agree, but the questions about the API allow StackApps to not be just a list of software which use this API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should we ban the api tag on MSE and reserve it to StackApps?

No. While Stack Apps is also suitable for questions about API use, the API is an officially supported feature and any bug reports or support requests that relate to it are welcome here on MSE.

See also: [Shouldn't the questions about Stack Apps be closed as off-topic there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244773/shouldnt-the-questions-about-stack-apps-be-closed-as-off-topic-there/)

Comment: So there's no problem having questions about the API on MSE and StackApps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

StackApps sounds better for it. MSE is for bickering about downvotes, StackApps is about creating bots that downvote! (jk)

StackApps people would be able to answer API questions better. It should be kept separate from MSE.

Comment: Yeah, it's worth noting that questions about the API which are answerable *do* actually get answers on Stack Apps. The backlog for bugs and other weird behaviours that require developer intervention will likely have to sit around for a response regardless of where they're posted.