# Expired and awarded bounties on the same question were awarded to another user

Tags: bug, bounties, expired-bounty

I posted two bounties on one of my questions ([Should the questions about the API be posted only on Stackapps (and not MSE)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235089/237701)):

- the first one was started in July with 50 points and was lost (not awarded to anyone)
- the second (and last) one was started with 100 points this month and has been awarded to Anna Lear ♦ after the grace period

The bounty is correctly displayed next to the answer of Anna Lear, and that's the only bounty displayed:

> [image: Anna Lear's answer]

See the [Bounties tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/237701/a-l?tab=bounties&sort=offered) on my profile:

> [image: Bounties]

According to this tab the user has been awarded the two bounties but:

- This user hasn't been awarded by any bounty from me
- The datetime for the 50 points bounty is wrong: if the user had been awarded it should have been in July

It seems that offering a bounty multiple times for the same question has caused problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I read the bounties tab you show us, the only thing bjb568's name mean there is that this user is the *last person who performed an edit* on one of the posts (question or answer) related to the questions on which you put a bounty. The name is *not* there to indicate *who got the bounty.*

So I don't see a problem there.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that. Thanks!